Is this a legit wet vent?
This is a follow-up from a previous question, I was encouraged to ask this revised question separately.
I am curious whether the venting on this set of connections meets code as a wet vent or not. Everything you see here is in the basement and below grade.


The first photo shows a new standpipe (2”), trap (1½”), and trap arm (1½”) for the washer. Where you see the A on that photo at the end of the trap arm that pipe goes about 4” through the wall to where you see the B on the second photo. As you can see it joins a 1½” x 3“ sanitary cross (if I’m identifying the fitting correctly) which goes down into a cast iron wye into the floor and out to the street. The vertical drop from the cross down into the cast iron is probably a foot or so.
The lighting doesn't show it but there is a main vertical cast iron drain stack behind the PVC in the second photo where the wye ties in. The vertical cast iron stack is presumably vented but I don't know where. There is also a second much longer (4'?) trap arm coming from a basement sink that goes into the right side of the cross the same way the washer drain ties in on the left side.
The only part of this that I have changed is that the setup in the first photo was previously rotated downward, with the bottom of the trap sitting on the floor and the arm sloping upward at about a 30° angle. It broke and I rebuilt it with what I believe to be the proper slope (¼” per foot down), and secured to the wall. Nothing else was changed. So whatever venting we have is what we have always had, and never had a problem with, but I'm just curious if it's right or not (kind of guessing not :( ).
This is in Massachusetts and the code is the state uniform plumbing code which I believe is based on UPC.
Thanks for any info!
